# Git For Server to sync changes

Tags: git, deployment, version-control, production

I am part of a team that is using git in a project which i working fine but the problem arises when we need to deploy changes to the server,2 people working on different branches have different code running.Is it possible that git can help merge those changes while deploying to server without having to merge branches and then deploy to server.

Comment: You can also create another branch (such as `production`) to merge your code with the other developer's code on local repo, and then deploy to the server with `production` branch.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible that git can help merge those changes while deploying to server without having to merge branches and then deploy to server.

No, it is not possible to merge changes without merging branches. By definition, merging requires branches. I suggest you read [this chapter from Pro Git](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging) for more information about how branching and merging are related.

Many projects will have a `master` branch which can be deployed to a production server. There are many different development workflows, most of which rely on developers creating a new branch for their work and then merging it into `master` when the work is complete. You need to develop a work flow for your team. See [my question on Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/165725/git-branching-and-tagging-best-practices) that discusses many of the issues involved. The answers also have some links for suggested work flows.